# what is best way read data from server and show on client browser

Tags: python, websocket, server-sent-events

websocket / sse are used to send data to client browser. Online stock quotes, or twitters updating timeline or feed are examples of it.

I have a page ( see image ) that ( should ) show data ( sql ) from server to browser ( page ).

when a button is clicked ( like a left/right arrow click, as seen in image ) it should show ( refresh ) new data. Will websocket be suitable for such a need.

If not then what should I use. Since i am using python will a web python framework ( cherrypy, flask ) be handy.

Am i thinking in proper direction ( considering I am relatively new to this )

[image: visualisation of report]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don´t need websockets to load data to a webpage dynamically. Instead, you can use jQuery´s **.load()** method to load a page and put it into a div. Here´s an example from jquery.org:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

And here´s the jQuery help page for the .load() method: http://api.jquery.com/load/.

Comment: Right. As long as the trigger to load new data originates on the browser side, you don't need WebSocket. If the trigger would be inserting new data into a database table, that's a different scenario.

Comment: is it efficient in speed ?.

Comment: @nish jQuery one or the WebSocket one?

Comment: is jquery method efficient in retrieving data ( enough that with every click as in the image ) it will display in quick time succession.

Comment: @nish Yes it is. Lots of websites use it without any problems.

Comment: @nish There is jquery.com. I also linked it in my answer. And there are some tutorials on YouTube too.